# How can I generate more than one CSV file in sas stored process?

Tags: csv, stored-procedures, sas, sas-macro

I have two SAS codes, one is for the HTML application and the other is the code itself. The code has two print procedures, each one is to generate a CSV file.

I have the HTML code bellow to generate two CSV files:

```
data _null_;     
  format infile $char256.;     
  input;    
  infile = resolve(_infile_);    
  file _webout;    
  put infile;    
cards4;    
  
<style>   
input[type='file'] {   
  border: 2px solid grey;   
  width: 500px;   
  length: 100%;  
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;  
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;  
  cursor: pointer;  
}   
  
input[type='submit'] {   
  border-radius: 10px;  
  cursor: pointer;  
}   
  
</style>                          
        <HTML>      
              
        <BODY>       
        <H2 align="center">Deseja atualizar a Base?<H2>      
        <H3 align="center">(Tempo estimado: 15 minutos)<H3>      
              
        <form action="http://mydir" method="post" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
        <input type="hidden" name="_program" value="/myprogram"> /*the code itself*/     
  
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">      

        <tr>   
        <td></td>   
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Atualizar"></td>      
        </tr>      
        </table>      
        </form>   
  
        </BODY>      
        </HTML>                
;;;;      
run;
```

The user must click at the button so two csv files will be downloaded to the user's pc.
And the code which the html is reading from has this print procedure to export the data:

```
%let hoje = %sysfunc(today(),date9.);
%let rc=%sysfunc(stpsrv_header(Content-type,application/vnd.ms-excel));  
%let rc=%sysfunc(stpsrv_header('Content-disposition','attachment; filename=temp.csv'));
%let rc=%sysfunc(stpsrv_header(Content-disposition,attachment%str(;) filename=FILE1_&HOJE..csv));  
%let _ODSSTYLE=PEARL;
  
ods csv file=_webout options(autofit_height='YES' FROZEN_HEADERS='YES' delimiter="|");
PROC PRINT DATA=FILE1 noobs LABEL 
style(HEADER)={color=black background=white font_weight=bold font_size=10pt font_face=CALIBRI width=1.8in just=c vjust=c} 
                                         style(DATA) = {background=white font_size=10pt font_face=CALIBRI};

format MYVAR $char.;  
RUN;

%let rc=%sysfunc(stpsrv_header(Content-disposition,attachment%str(;) filename=FILE2_&HOJE..csv));  

PROC PRINT DATA=FILE2 noobs LABEL 
style(HEADER)={color=black background=white font_weight=bold font_size=10pt font_face=CALIBRI width=1.8in just=c vjust=c} 
                                         style(DATA) = {background=white font_size=10pt font_face=CALIBRI};
RUN;
ods csv close;    

ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP

FILE=_webout

STYLE=minimal;
```

The intention here is to generate two CSV files in the HTML application.

But at the application, it only exports the first file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Even if you could generate two or more files how would the consumer receive them?  Did you consider sending a ZIP file with the CSV files embedded instead?  Then you only need to send one file.

Comment: Tom is correct. Browsers can only download one file at a time when it is requested. You'll need to zip your files in SAS and then send that file out to the user. There are a few different ways you can zip stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try that!

Comment: Just make two requests, calling SAS with Javascript.  For the download, this macro might also help to clean up the code:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__streamfile_8sas.html

Answer (score 0):

You've already got what I'd have suggested when I first read the title - a separate "create CSV" job and a "download CSV" job.

So on your "download CSV" job, why not make 2 links instead of one?  One for each link.  That's the user friendly approach, and how most sites would present data like this - as separate links for each file.

If this won't work with your architecture, the "one zip file" approach is also appropriate (particularly if the file is very large and you'd want to zip it anyway), but I tend to feel that separate links makes sense much of the time.

Comment: You could also use javascript to call two STPs, they'd both download alternative CSVs then

Answer (score 0):

My coworker found the solution:

```
proc export data=FILE1
outfile="PATH/FILE1.xlsx"
dbms=xlsx
replace;
run;

proc export data=FILE2
outfile="PATH/FILE2.xlsx"
dbms=xlsx
replace;
run;

ods package(newzip) open nopf;
ods package(newzip) add file="PATH/FILE1.xlsx" ;
ods package(newzip) add file="PATH/FILE2.xlsx";
ods package(newzip) publish archive
properties(
archive_name='MYFILE.zip'
archive_path="PATH"
);
ods package(newzip) close;

data _null_;
file _webout recfm=s;
infile "PATH/MYFILE.zip" recfm=n;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
rc = stpsrv_header('Content-type','application/zip');
rc = stpsrv_header('Content-disposition',"attachment; filename=MYFILE.zip");
end;
input c $char1.;
put c $char1. @@;
run;
```

It turns out that Stored Process doesn't output more than one file, so the best way of doing it is exporting the files inside a zip document.